# Does Google CA accept IP addresses as SubjectAltNames and how can I go about this?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, certificate, subdomain, san

How can I use an IP address instead of a domain in a subject alt name and how can I get this approved by Google Certificate Authority?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use IP addresses for one of SAN entries with Google Certificate Authority Service.

**[Update 2023-06-29]**

Google Trust Services will issue TLS certificates that contain an IP address instead of a domain name in the certificate subject field.

However, the lifetime of the certificate is only 10 days.

This [FAQ](https://pki.goog/faq/#faq-IPCerts) has more details.